# Как получить кладр код в <input name=код">

Tags: input, кладр

Не могу получить кладр код в

```
<input name=city"> и <input name="region">
```

Если коротко то в mySQL, name="" записывает город к примеру Москва
А нужно чтобы name="" передовал в БД сам кладр код, к пример кода 7700000000000 - города Москвы
Причем если посмотреть исходный код формы к примеру в гугл там такая запись

```
<input name="city" autocomplete="off" data-kladr-type="city" data-kladr-
id="7700000000000">
```

как вы видите что кладр код есть но передается он в

```
data-kladr-id="7700000000000"
```

Вот [CSS JS HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/limbo1991/yvk3atgx/2/)

PHP Файл

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <!-- КЛАДР  -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../themes/kladr/css/jquery.kladr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../themes/kladr/js/jquery.kladr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../themes/kladr/js/form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- КЛАДР  -->
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $host="localhost:3306";
    $user="root";
    $pass="hahin1991";
    $db_name="cachebank";
    $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);

//Если переменная city передана
    if (isset($_POST["city"])) {
    //Вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `city_region` (`city`, `region`) 
            VALUES ('".$_POST['city']."','".$_POST['region']."')");
    //Если вставка прошла успешно
        if ($sql) {
            echo "<add>Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу.</add>";
        } else {
            echo "<error>Произошла ошибка.</error>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <table>
        <div class="address">
            <h1>Форма для ввода адреса</h1>
            <form action="" method="post" class="js-form-address">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Информация о проживание</legend>
                <div class="field">
                  <label for="city">Город проживания </label>
                  <input name="city">
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                  <label for="region">Регион </label>
                  <input name="region"><br>
              </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div class="tooltip" style="display: none;"><b></b><span></span></div>
          <input type="submit" value="Отправить Заявку">
      </form>
  </div>
</table>
<table><fieldset>
    <?php
//Удаляем, если что
    if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
        $sql = mysql_query('DELETE FROM `city_region` WHERE `ID` = "'.$_GET['del'].'"');
        if ($sql) {
            echo "<ok>Товар удален.</ok>";
        } else {
            echo "<error>Произошла ошибка.</error>";
        }
    }


//Получаем данные
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT `ID`, `city`, `region` FROM `city_region`');
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
       echo "<div style='font-size: 16px;font-weight: 600;color: #795548;'> #";echo $result['ID']." ".$result['city']." ".$result['region']."  - <a style='color: #0288d1;' href='?del=".$result['ID']."'>Удалить</a></div><br>";
   }

   ?>
</fieldset></table>
</body>
```

Один из JS все настройки вроде тут

```
$(function () {
    var
    $region = $('[name="region"]'),
    $city = $('[name="city"]');


    var $tooltip = $('.tooltip');

    $.kladr.setDefault({
        parentInput: '.js-form-address',
        verify: true,
        select: function (obj) {
            setLabel($(this), obj.type);
            $tooltip.hide();
        },
        check: function (obj) {
            var $input = $(this);

            if (obj) {
                setLabel($input, obj.type);
                $tooltip.hide();
            }
            else {
                showError($input, 'Введено неверно');
            }
        },
        checkBefore: function () {
            var $input = $(this);

            if (!$.trim($input.val())) {
                $tooltip.hide();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    $region.kladr('type', $.kladr.type.region);
    $city.kladr('type', $.kladr.type.city);

    function setLabel($input, text) {
        text = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.substr(1).toLowerCase();
        $input.parent().find('label').text(text);
    }

    function showError($input, message) {
        $tooltip.find('span').text(message);

        var inputOffset = $input.offset(),
            inputWidth = $input.outerWidth(),
            inputHeight = $input.outerHeight();

        var tooltipHeight = $tooltip.outerHeight();

        $tooltip.css({
            left: (inputOffset.left + inputWidth + 10) + 'px',
            top: (inputOffset.top + (inputHeight - tooltipHeight) / 2 - 1) + 'px'
        });

        $tooltip.show();
    }
});
```

Я сам не в силах, но если найдутся добре люди то буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая что вы передаете все через $_POST, то уходят данные из value у инпута, если таковые имеются.

Можно использовать что-то типа такого

```
$city.kladr({select: function(obj) {

    $city.val(obj.id);

  }});
```

Но, будет не совсем красиво, потому что наименование города автоматически заменится на его идентификатор.

Я бы сделал вот так

Это в форму:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="true-city" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="true-region" value="">
```

Это в скрипт:

```
$city.kladr({select: function(obj) {

    $('input[name=true-city]').val(obj.id);

  }});

$region.kladr({select: function(obj) {

    $('input[name=true-region]').val(obj.id);

  }});
```

а в php дело за малым - забрать $_POST['true-city'] и $_POST['true-region']

Ночью ничего лучше в голову не приходит)

Comment: Спасибо большое, все прекрасно работает!